# What is the likelihood of effective repair of septal perforations greater than 2 cm?

Tags: surgery, septoplasty

With septal perforations >2 cm that have clear borders what is the likelihood of establishing blood supply over the inserted cartilage after septal repair?

How much of the existing mucosa can be grafted and are there alternative sources if nasal (likely turbinate) mucosa is insufficient to cover the repaired perforation?

There are several studies outlining patient outcomes with a success rate of 90-97% but procedures and complications are not provided in detail. Tissue is harvested from the hairline and ear but this does not serve the same function as nasal mucosa. These studies appear to be inconsistent with surgical statistics and hospital records.

The alternative methods (provided by the Mayo Clinic) of replacing tissue by growing it from patient stem cells is costly, impractical, and not a commonly recognized approach.

Comment: Your question is very specific on patient details. Have you read [this](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: It's a general question about medium to large septal perforations with clearly defined borders (no flaps).

Comment: Okay, just checking. :)